# Understanding Fuzzy Composition operations

Tags: relations, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

There are two common forms of composition operation in Fuzzy Theory:

- max–min composition
- max–product composition

Let `R` be a relation that relates elements from universe X to universe Y, and let `S` be a relation that relates elements from universe Y to universe Z.

Relation R and S are as follows

$R = \begin{array}{c c} &
\begin{array}{c c c} y_1 & y_2 \\
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{c c c}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{array} 
&
\left[\begin{array}{c c c}
 0.1 & 0.3 \\
 0.4 & 0.2 \\
 0.8 & 0.6
\end{array}\right] 
\end{array}$
$S = \begin{array}{c c} &
\begin{array}{c c c} z_1 & z_2 & z_3 \\
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{c c c}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
\end{array} 
&
\left[\begin{array}{c c c}
 0.1 & 0.3 & 0.2 \\
 0.6 & 0.4 & 0.5 \\
\end{array}\right] 
\end{array}$

Now relation between $x_1$ and $z_1$ can be calculated as

> `max–min composition`= max[min(0.1, 0.1), min(0.3, 0.6)] = 0.3
>
> `max–product composition` = max[(0.1*0.1), (0.3*0.6)] = 0.18

In `Crisp Set` it is easy to get the intuition i.e. if $x_1$ related $y_1$ and if $y_1$ is related to $z_1$ then with transitive property we can say $x_1$ is related to $z_1$. But in the case of `Fuzzy Set Theory` what these operations intuitively say. What does it mean to say, $x_1$ is related to $z_1$ with `0.3` in the case of max–min composition and  with `0.18` in the case of max–product composition intuitively.